# Android setText() Syntax Error On Tokens

Tags: java, android, settext

Okay, I've got the makings of a really simple Android program here.  I decided to start out with something simple but also relatively useful.  Eventually, I hope to have an application that stores and displays study cards.  I feel like not being able to get past a TextView is a bad omen.  I've looked at several dozen examples and researched common problems new users have with setText(), but to no avail.  Here are the relevant lines of code:

From my .java file:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
tv1.setText("New text");
```

.... and so on

Eclipse is marking the line containing "setText" and giving me the following syntactical errors:

Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) //underlining the period after tv1

Syntax error on token ""New text"", delete this token

Comment: put this code in oncreate method.
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    tv1.setText("New text");

Comment: write `TextView` in `onCreate` method

Comment: Thank you all for the very quick responses.  I had actually just come to the same conclusion myself.  I had previously tried moving the first line there, but not the second.  I guess this leads me to another question though.  Eventually, I was planning on updating the textview each time a new card was brought to the forefront of the deck.  Seeing now, though, that I can't simply call setText() wherever I want, will I be able to use this later on to update the card display, or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Nevermind, got to my own solution again.  I suppose that it's always going to be in a method, because it's going to require a gesturedetector to activate.  I thank all of you very much though.  The whole basis of the Java within Android thing kinda just clicked into place for me I think.  To be fair, I may have done better had I not chosen the middle of the night to learn a new language.  Thank y'all again for all the extremely fast answers.

Comment: I sincerely suggest you to go through the concepts and programming of java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the initialization of textview to `onCreate`.

```
TextView tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1); 
// initialize after settting layout to activtiy
tv1.setText("New text");
// the above statement must be within a method 
}
```

Your initialization of `textview` is outside any method. You should initialize your textview only after setting the layout to the activity. So textview is initialized in `onCreate`. This  `tv1.setText("New text")` statement must be within a method.

Initializing your `textview` inside activity `onCreate` is better.

Comment: you are answer is correct, but does not explain why he gets the syntax  error on token(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    tv1.setText("New text");

}
```

place your code inside the oncreate method .

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView tv1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            tv1.setText("New text");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
tv1.setText("New text");
```

Always use this kind of things inside the methods like onCreate ,onresume and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
just because you initailize textview locally and set the textview 
outside onCreate method,you got this error.define textview globally solve ur issue;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
tv1.setText("New text");
}
```

Comment: this is totally wrong. does not answer the question.have you tried what you have suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Move TextView object into onCreate() method and then call setText method on it. Here is Your Required Code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    tv1.setText("New text");
    }
```